# Can't find link using capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, capybara

I'm using cucumber with capybara to test my app. However, i can't seem to find an anchor link in my page. I have used `save_and_open_page` to debug the particular step, and this is the relevant framgent of the output page:

```
<ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
  <li><a href="http://www.example.com/en/accounts/login">Login</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.example.com/en/accounts/register">Register</a></li>
</ul>
```

My scenario's step that fails, includes the following code:

```
expect(page).to have_link("Login")
expect(page).to have_link("Register")
```

The failure message i get from capybara is:

```
Capybara::ExpectationNotMet: expected to find link "Login" but there were no matches. Also found "", which matched the selector but not all filters.
```

I have tried to replace my expectations using an id, name, etc, but with no luck.

Does anyone might have an idea on how i can get this to work?

EDIT:

A piece of information that might prove useful:

The two links mentioned previously reside within a partial which is included in the layout of the page i'm visiting in my tests:

- `_title_bar.html.haml` : includes the Login and Register links as shown above
- `layout.html.haml`     : includes the _partial.html.haml partial
- `login.html.haml`      : is rendered using layout.html.haml as templat

e.

I've noticed that when i put the links in the login.html.haml directly, my tests pass. When i include them however in the layout.html.haml or _title_bar.html.haml, capybara fails to resolve them.

Comment: Do other matcher's work in this block?  Please post your full spec file or at least the example that contains these two `expect` lines.

Comment: I've posted my full step definition that fails.

Comment: Have a look the the debugging techniques under "Debugging capybara" http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/

Comment: Can you post the source code of your templates & partials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell from the information provided, but here are a couple of things to look for:

1. By default, Capybara does not find hidden elements. If the links are hidden via JavaScript or CSS, that would give the behaviour you're seeing. You can override that by calling `expect(page).to have_link("Login", visible: false)`
2. Depending on the driver you're using, Capybara can be sensitive to poorly-formed markup in the page. Is it possible that when you move the links to `layout.html.haml` or `_title_bar.html.haml`, it ends up inside of an element that is nested incorrectly?

Comment: Accepted because of the second part of the answer. I have inspected my  partials and indeed the links where not placed where intended. Thanks a lot.